# ASP.NET identity with Entity Framework code-first using Oracle 11g Express edition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

Can we use ASP.NET identity with Entity Framework code-first using Oracle 11g Express edition?

I have googled this but haven't found anything closely related.

Comment: EF supports Oracle DB. This will be just a different driver specified in a connection string, everything else is handled by EF for you. Here is a link to study: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/InstallEntityConfig.htm#ODPNT8266

Comment: Can I have a look at your migration class? This might help me to find an answer for you.